# PostGIS for GPX analysis

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, gpx

I have GPX trails of vehicles/bikes of a particular city. Meaning, lat/lon, timestamp of bike trails from where a particular bike started and ended at different hours of the day. I have sets of these trails for different bikes roaming around the city.

Now, I want to know if it is possible with PostGIS+pgRouting+any other combination to know how much time it takes to go from point A to point B in a particular range of hours by using the data I already have. Assume I have enough data for the city in terms of bike trails.

I do not want to use OSM data. But, if it is required, I am fine with using it.

Sample data:

> BikeID, Lat, Lon, timeStamp
>      
>  1234,13.9845583,77.6052433,1431849998287
>      
>  1234,13.9846133,77.6052366,1431850069237
>      
>  1234,13.9846333,77.6051566,1431850102429
>      
>  95,13.9845683,77.6050683,1431850138314
>      
>  95,13.9845683,77.6050683,1431850172455

Comment: I don't think you even need pgRouting. You can use the 2nd example from [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html), feed that to [ST_Distance](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance.html), and then divide by  end timeStamp - start timeStamp, group by each bikeID. Happy to help with the SQL, if that is the approach that you are looking for?

Comment: @john: Maybe I didn't frame the question correctly. What I want is given this historical data, for any point to other point, I want time it takes to travel. Sort of ETA for a route. I will need route- edges and how much it takes for the edge.

Comment: So, what you say is, if I have a new set of start and end points to predict time, I will use them to make line, distance etc? If those points are available in my data, it will match the route? Sorry, I am new to PostGIS.

Comment: Sorry, no, what I was suggesting will allow you to calculate a route for any given edge or an entire journey for any given bike ID. But, to find the time for some arbitrary route using multiple edges from different routes on different days, then, yes, you would need to feed all the edges (calcutlated as I suggested) into pgrouting.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you rewrite entire steps as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Will be later today, as very busy right now. Maybe someone else answer first.

Comment: @JohnBarça: It looks nobody else is answering this question. Can you help?

Comment: He, he, I have realized it is a bit harder than I thought. Do you a road network to overlay it on, or do you want to actually form a grid based on any pair of consecutive x and y points?

Comment: :) I have no idea what you just said. This is how I wanted to do: 1) Use OSM data to get edges of a city's route. 2) use historical data to match with edges and see time it takes to cross the edge. 3) To calculate time for arbitrary points, get edges and lookup from previous analysis and sum up the times.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. The points from above, from each biki id, would have to be converted to an actual network by using something like OSM to find nearest point and generate edges, before any of this can be fed to pgrouting. OK, it is a somewhat non-trivial problem, you will have to be patient, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Sure. :) Will wait for your solution. If you want some sample data, you can take from here: [link](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=152883) . It is taxi data from China.

Comment: No that's cool. Sent you an email.